System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed context instance
I have a problem occurring when I execute:
await alarmHandler.InitRedis("setting");


System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed context instance. A common cause of this error is disposing a context instance that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling 'Dispose' on the context instance, or wrapping it in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.

This is my code:

program.cs

builder.Services.AddHostedService<Alarm>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AlarmHnadler>();


Alarm

public class Alarm : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    private readonly MqttFactory mqttFactory;
    private readonly MqttBrokerOptions? _mqttBrokerOptions;
    private readonly IoTDbContext _context;
    private readonly RabbitMQSet _rabbitMQSet;
    private readonly IDbContextFactory<IoTDbContext> _dbContextFactory;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private  AlarmHnadler alarmHandler;
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;
    private IModel? _channel { get; set; }
    private readonly RedisUtils _redisUtils;

    public Alarm(IModel channel, IOptions<MqttBrokerOptions> mqttBrokerOptions, IConfiguration configuration,
        SmsClient smsClient, VoiceMessagingService voiceMessagingService,
        IDbContextFactory<IoTDbContext> dbContextFactory, IMapper mapper,
        IHubContext<AlarmHub> hubContext,IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
    {
        mqttFactory = new MqttFactory();
        _mqttBrokerOptions = mqttBrokerOptions.Value;
        _dbContextFactory = dbContextFactory;
        _context = dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext();
        _channel = channel;
        _mapper = mapper;
        _redisUtils = new RedisUtils(configuration, _context, _mapper);
        _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
        using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
             alarmHandler = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AlarmHnadler>();
        }
    }
public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var userName = "Server";
        var password = "123456".AESEncrypt(mode: CipherMode.ECB, padding: PaddingMode.Zeros, base64: false);
        var mqttClientOptions = new MqttClientOptionsBuilder()
            .WithTcpServer(_mqttBrokerOptions?.Host, _mqttBrokerOptions?.Port)
            .WithProtocolVersion(MQTTnet.Formatter.MqttProtocolVersion.V500)
            .WithCredentials(userName, password)
            .WithCleanSession()
            .Build();
        MqttSet.Client = mqttFactory.CreateMqttClient();
        MqttSet.Client.ConnectedAsync += Client_ConnectedAsync;
        MqttSet.Client.DisconnectedAsync += Client_DisconnectedAsync;
        MqttSet.Client.ApplicationMessageReceivedAsync += Client_ApplicationMessageReceivedAsync;
        await MqttSet.Client.ConnectAsync(mqttClientOptions, CancellationToken.None);
       
            await alarmHandler.InitRedis("setting");      
    }


AlarmHnadler

 public class AlarmHnadler : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly SmsClient _smsClient;
        private readonly VoiceMessagingService _voiceMessagingService;
        private readonly IoTDbContext _context;
        private readonly IDbContextFactory<IoTDbContext> _dbContextFactory;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;
        private readonly IDatabase _redisDB;
        private readonly AlarmUtils _alarmUtil;
        private readonly RedisUtils _redisUtils;
        private Dictionary<string, string> gatewaytAlarmDict { get; set; }
        private readonly IHubContext<AlarmHub> _hubContext;

        private IModel? _channel { get; set; }
        public IBatch batch { get; set; }

        public AlarmHnadler(IModel channel, IDbContextFactory<IoTDbContext> dbContextFactory,
            IConfiguration configuration, IHubContext<AlarmHub> hubContext,
            IMapper mapper, SmsClient smsClient, VoiceMessagingService voiceMessagingService)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
            _dbContextFactory = dbContextFactory;
            _alarmUtil = new AlarmUtils(_configuration);
            var settingValue = _configuration["RedisDb"];
            _channel = channel;
            int.TryParse(settingValue, out int result);
            _redisDB = RedisClient.GetDatabase(result);
            _context = dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext();
            _smsClient = smsClient;
            _voiceMessagingService = voiceMessagingService;
            _mapper = mapper;
            gatewaytAlarmDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            _hubContext = hubContext;
            setGatewayAlarmDictValue();
            batch = _redisDB.CreateBatch();
            _redisUtils = new RedisUtils(_configuration, _context, _mapper);
        }
          public async Task InitRedis(string tableName)
        {
            switch (tableName)
            {
                case "setting":
                    batch.KeyDeleteAsync("setting");
                    var alarmPointSettings =
                        await _context.Set<AlarmPointSettings>().Where(a => a.Status == 1).ToListAsync();
                    var result =
                        _mapper.Map<List<AlarmPointSettings>, List<AlarmPointSettingsRedis>>(alarmPointSettings);
                    var settingR = result.Select(item => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item))
                        .Select((json, index) => new { Id = alarmPointSettings[index].Id.ToString(), Json = json })
                        .ToList();
                    foreach (var r in settingR)
                    {
                        batch.HashSetAsync("setting", r.Id, r.Json);
                    }

                    batch.Execute();
                    break;
}

If you could help me solve this problem, I would be very grateful.
I no longer inject the context directly; instead, I use ContextFactory to generate it.I think this problem was solved.But i don't know why.The area circled in red in the image below is my modification.
enter image description here
ps:I initially didn't use dependency injection; instead, I directly instantiated objects (using 'new'), which also worked.Like this
// alarmHandler = new AlarmHnadler(_channel, _dbContextFactory, configuration, hubContext,
        //     _context, _mapper, smsClient, voiceMessagingService);


using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
{
     alarmHandler = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AlarmHnadler>();
}

Here is the documentation for that CreateScope method. It says:

Once this is disposed, any scoped services that have been resolved from the ServiceProvider will also be disposed.

The whole point of creating a scope is to use objects within that scope. Create the scope and the AlarmHandler where you expect to use them, use them, then dispose them. You can't create them and dispose them in one place and expect to use them elsewhere.

It's strange that the alarmHandler still exists after leaving the using{} block, but the context injected into the alarmHandler is released.To verify this,I write this   using (IServiceScope scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
{
scopedProcessingService =
scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService();
Console.WriteLine("create "+scopedProcessingService.GetHashCode());
}
        await scopedProcessingService.DoWorkAsync(stoppingToken);DoWorkAsync was still executed.


@slimshady, there's nothing strange about it at all. You create the object and assign it to a member variable. Of course it will still exist, until you set that field to null. Even then the object will still exist, although it will be inaccessible because you won't have a reference to it. Disposing an object doesn't make that object cease to exist. It simply releases certain managed and/or unmanaged resources as specified by the author. It's just like a Form in WinForms. When you close it, it is disposed. It can't be shown again but it still exists, so you can still get data from it.

@slimshady, note that this is why you should not be using a field in the first place, if you're using scoped services. The whole point of the scope is that you can only use the generated service within that scope so you should be using a variable declared within that scope to refer to it.

I think I know why the alarmHandler still exists (initially, I thought that once disposed was executed, the alarmHandler would disappear）,But I still puzzled as to why the context disappeared.（I injected the context into the alarmHandler. Why did the context disappear while the alarmHandler did not，Why can't the context show again?）

@slimshady, the context didn't disappear. It was disposed, because it was also created within that scope that was disposed. The exception you're getting is ObjectDisposedException, not NullReferenceException. The object is there but it cannot be used because it has been disposed. The objects created as arguments for your AlarmHnadler constructor are done so within the scope and so will disposed when exiting that scope. By the way, note the spelling error in AlarmHnadler.
